# Using LatLng in backend

Tags: java, arrays, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to use a `ArrayList<LatLng>` in my server backend. I'm currently using Android Studio, and realize that there are certain dependancies only the app or backend have access to.
 Unfortunately, I'm trying to convert a GeoPT object in to a LatLng.

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "requestIcons")
public ArrayList<LatLng> requestIcons(){
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    ArrayList<LatLng> coordlist = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    Query q = new Query("Request");
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

    for (Entity result: pq.asIterable() ){
      GeoPt get = (GeoPt) result.getProperty("Location");
       double lat = (double) get.getLatitude();
        double lng = (double)  get.getLongitude();



        coordlist.add(pq.asIterable(), new LatLng(lat,lng)  );

    }
}
```

I can't seem to initialze a LatLng Object. It gives me the error saying the LatLng package has private access. What I'm trying to do here is pass an array of addresses in to my app. Are there any methods to initialize a LatLng object or do I have to write a custom java wrapper?

Comment: Is this the library you try to import? com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

Comment: *do I have to write a custom java wrapper?* LatLng is essentially just a class that holds 2 double values

Comment: I can't import it. Gradle wouldn't let me add the dependancy. 

Tim, How exactly do I write this new wrapper? I have a custom java file IconWrapper.java.Do I just add 

 //      public static void MyAdd(double lat, double lng){}

Comment: the required dependency is the following:'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'. If you're getting the "Over 65K Methods" error, you should follow these tips: https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Sevle - I use 7.8.0 for debug purposes. What seems to be the problem is I can't add the dependancy under the "backend" section of my gradle scripts. It bounces back with an unfound error everytime.